# jQuery attach custom event to &.fn.text()

Tags: jquery

I'd like to fire a custom event in the .text() function in jQuery. It seems like this should be possible but i'm having some trouble figuring out the closures(?).  something like:

```
jQuery.fn.text = function(){
    _text = jQuery.fn.text;
    // fire a custom event/do something
    jQuery.apply(_text,arguments);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll get an infinite loop (recursive) with that. You need to save a reference to the original text function before overwriting it. You also need to return the result of the call to `_text`.

```
_text = jQuery.fn.text;
jQuery.fn.text = function(){
    // fire a custom event/do something
    return _text.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Comment: good point.  though making this change doesn't seem to affect any selected elements later on,  running this in fire bug fails to change the posts:

_text = jQuery.fn.text;
$.fn.text = function(){
    jQuery.apply(_text,arguments);
}
$("div.post-text").text("foo");

Comment: I believe the error is in your application of `apply()`. See my edit. You also need to return the result of `_text` in your new function.